Connecting Pressure Sensor to MKR Wifi 1010
I have Pressure Sensor YD4080 with the following characteristics : Input Volt. 5-12V (it will operate at 5V),  Operating Intensity : <=3mA, Output V. : 0.5V to 4.5V, Output V. from pressure operating range : 0.5V to 3V.(0 to 5Atm)
This meets the specifications for MKR wifi 1010, but,  in order to protect the MRK analog input (Max 3.3V/7mA) from unexpected pressure behavior,
In this case of very small intensity, is it safe to place 3.3V. zener diode without any resistors at analog input?
Thanks!!!
